# Enter capthca value on behalf of user

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a situation: my Java program deployed on a server fetches a page from a website, which has a captcha image. The image will be displayed to the end-user and the end-user will enter the value of the captcha and submit that page to the server. The server will submit that value to the main website.

I have tried it using http client but on submitting, it says invalid image value.

Please help me.
 code to show user capthca image

```
HttpClient hc=new HttpClient();
GetMethod gm=new GetMethod("https://abc.com/register");
int sta=hc.executeMethod(gm);
String line=gm.getResponseBodyAsString();

    urlStr="https://abc.com/captchaImage";
    URL url=new URL(urlStr);
    BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(url);
    ImageIO.write(img1, "jpg", out);
```

submit requets to abc.com

```
HttpClient hc=new HttpClient();
PostMethod hm=new PostMethod("https://abc.com/submit");
hm.addParameter("pwd","Asdf@123456" );
hm.addParameter("confirmPwd","Asdf@123456");
hm.addParameter("hintQues","Birth+City");
hm.addParameter("hintAns","fdgf");
hm.addParameter("captchavalue",request.getParameter("cap"));
hm.addParameter("register","Register");
int returnCode = hc.executeMethod(hm);
out.println(hm.getResponseBodyAsString());
```

Comment: I doubt you'll get a lot of help from this community. Captcha spoofing isn't exactly high up on the priorities list...

Comment: You might find some clues in this article: http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=68&id=4#article

Comment: I can't see the problem everybody else sees, obviously. The OP doesn't ask how to read Captchas, he want to send the user's input (which should be the captchas text) to the captcha's server. Anyway. user1047873, you're not giving us enough information - we need to see your code. From the information you gave us, we can only say that you did something wrong :). Show us the submitting code.

Comment: @Slanec It sounds like the OP is trying to build a captcha deciphering farm, a mechanical Turk help for spamming. Unless the OP can show in good faith this is not the case, I'd rather avoid helping such an enterprise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not analyzed how abc.com's registration work, but I would bet that it uses either some hidden field (for which I see no parameter in your code), or a cookie to remember which captcha was displayed to the user, and thus verify if the captcha value sent by the browser is the right value.

Since you don't send the hidden field value, and since you're using a fresh new HttpClient instance, you're sending a captcha value to the server, but it has no way to know for which captcha you're sending this value, and so can't verify it.

Try reusing the same instance of HttpClient than the one used to get the registration page from the server. This way, cookies stored in the HttpClient's state will be sent back to the server.

Comment: thanks for help .they are using cookies to identify the value

Comment: i have add this metod for retuning httpclient object /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */ but still problem exist i think it may be because i am reading image using image io is there any method for reading imahe in httpclient api
package captcha;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;

/**
 *
 * @author 30129000
 */

public class HttpClientObj {
   static  HttpClient hc=new HttpClient();
    public static HttpClient getHttpClientObj()
    {
        return hc;
    }
}

Comment: but problem still exist.i think this may be due to imageio is used  for reading image is there any method in http client to read image

Comment: Execute a GET method, get the response body as byte[], and use ImageIO to transform this byte[] into an image.